# EPSON ESCPOS QRCode >380 characters not print

Tags: c#, qr-code, epson, escpos

I can not print more than 380 characters in a qr code .

Follows the code in C # :

```
    protected ASCIIEncoding m_encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string QRdata = @"35150909165024000175590000193130072726117830|20150924062259|50.00||hdMEPiER6rjZKyKA+4+voi1nncxsAGFbYsEEqnh04SbvUEI/haUF4GUBPxT6Q2Uhf9f8QYgxiwxWo3GxRrvj4WnNeTYgAqUAYmOANPItNkOw0CppmZ4R8i1ZOlnftVhksCM0zrl4RiKgoazbN44hUu2nQf0W/JLvFXzXu12JlcSThNtmyJ6m9WBsMc/sf9BE14HDoXMyKRIQYt5TkEjilHH9Ffa0saRyUIp+Fji89/Moq8YCCFC+qC44XGxsvNCeeHUNOc1LgPP0DbU1miwpVnrBlEl87RU8Iy0r8fN/fNhbcStkwfTEvhYvZz42nEKHrmGTpGZYkHuTFCNZPq7aCA==";
        int store_len = QRdata.Length + 3;
                        byte store_pL = (byte)(store_len % 256);
                        byte store_pH = (byte)(store_len / 256);


                         string txt = m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, store_pL, store_pH, 49, 80, 48 }); //FUNCTION 180
            txt += QRdata;
            txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 69, 48 });//FUNCTION 169
            txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 67, 5 });//FUNCTION 167
            txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 4, 0, 49, 65, 50, 0 });//FUNCTION 165
            txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 81, 48 });//FUNCTION 181
```

When trying to print appears as follows:

[image: print]

Comment: Show, please, how do you use the string? As I understand you send it to serial port. Why don't you use byte array then? It looks like ASCII is your problem, because it is 7-bit encoding, but your low part of length exceeds 7-bits, so you get `?` in `txt` variable. You can use `Encoding m_encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");` and set same encoding for serial port, or use byte array from the beginning. BTW, can you try to print QR code with your current code for text having length between 128 and 255?

Comment: l'm using Winspool to print.
I changed my code to send byte to the winspool with this encoding and worked perfectly.
Before printed up to 380 characters.
Now it worked, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped, I posted an answer in case if anybody will look for the same problem.

Comment: I used your code to print qrcode and it works flawlessly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASCII is a problem, since it is 7-bit encoding, but `store_PL` value is greater than 127 (takes 8 bits). The following is demonstration of whats going on:

```
ASCIIEncoding m_encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string QRdata = @"35150909165024000175590000193130072726117830|20150924062259|50.00||hdMEPiER6rjZKyKA+4+voi1nncxsAGFbYsEEqnh04SbvUEI/haUF4GUBPxT6Q2Uhf9f8QYgxiwxWo3GxRrvj4WnNeTYgAqUAYmOANPItNkOw0CppmZ4R8i1ZOlnftVhksCM0zrl4RiKgoazbN44hUu2nQf0W/JLvFXzXu12JlcSThNtmyJ6m9WBsMc/sf9BE14HDoXMyKRIQYt5TkEjilHH9Ffa0saRyUIp+Fji89/Moq8YCCFC+qC44XGxsvNCeeHUNOc1LgPP0DbU1miwpVnrBlEl87RU8Iy0r8fN/fNhbcStkwfTEvhYvZz42nEKHrmGTpGZYkHuTFCNZPq7aCA==";
int store_len = QRdata.Length + 3; // 414
byte store_pL = (byte)(store_len % 256); // 158
byte store_pH = (byte)(store_len / 256); // 1
byte[] data = new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, store_pL, store_pH, 49, 80, 48 }; //FUNCTION 180
string txt = m_encoding.GetString(data);
byte[] invalidData = m_encoding.GetBytes(txt);
```

The original value of data (expected one):

```
1d 28 6b 9e 01 31 50 30
```

The actual data the serial port receives (due to failure to encode `158` value in 7-bit ASCII):

```
1d 28 6b 3f 01 31 50 30
```

As you can see, the value `158 (0x9e)` is changed to `63 (0x3f)`, since unknown symbol was encoded as `?`.

So, there are 2 solutions to the problem. One is to use `Encoding m_encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");` encoding, or any other extended ASCII encoding, but it should be synchronized between byte encoding you use in your code and settings of serial port. And another solution is not to use strings at all, but use byte arrays.