# ESC/POS 124Chars limit in QRcode printing

Tags: qr-code, escpos

I'm having an issue, regarding printing commands through ESC/POS to print a QR code, with more than 124 chars. I have seen different posts on Stack Overflow, but can't understand what is wrong with this.

To contextualize, the idea, is to print a qrcode in a receipt. The data is written to a text file, and after that is used by a service (rawbt) which prints the receipt in a thermal printer (those small ones)

I have a code that prints until 124 chars of data in qrcode correctly, but can't figure out how to print more in the same QR. extra text just shows up above QR code.

```
string QrData = "123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 XX";
int store_len = (QrData).Length + 3;

byte store_pL = (byte)(store_len % 256);
byte store_pH = (byte)(store_len / 256);


byte[] b = new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 4, 0, 49, 65, 50, 0 };            
byte[] b1 = new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 67, 9 };               
byte[] b2 = new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 69, 48 };              
byte[] b3 = new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, store_pL, store_pH, 49, 80, 48 };
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(QrData);
byte[] b4 = new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 81, 48 };
```

after that just use BinaryWriter to write this to the text file.

I've already tried other encodings, like utf-8 and iso-8859-1, but no luck.

Also did some play with store_pL and store_pH.
Did also some tests, when if the qrdata.length is > 124, adds up 128 to it, making the store_pL higher, and setting the store_pH to 0. If store_pH is higher than 0, no printing occurs.

note: this is a xamarin app.

Anyone knows please how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't show enough of the source code. What's the use of the b arrays ?

Comment: hi, i write them into a text file using binary writer:
using (BinaryWriter binWriter =
    new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
    {
    binWriter.Write(Constants.centerAlign);
    binWriter.Write(b);
    binWriter.Write(b1);
    binWriter.Write(b2);
    binWriter.Write(b3);
    binWriter.Write(bytes);
    binWriter.Write(b4);
    binWriter.Write(m_encoding.GetBytes(buffer));
    binWriter.Write(Constants.lineBreak);
    }

Comment: Are we deemed to decode them mentally ?

Comment: For example, how about changing the last `9` in `b2` to a value between `3` and `8`?

Comment: hi @kunif, that changes the "size" of the qr code, not changing the max length of data (124 chars).

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't it depend on the vendor and model of printer you're using? Why not ask your printer vendor if there are any restrictions?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with an Epson TM-m30II.

I found a solution for this problem. The problem is well described in this post:

[EPSON ESCPOS QRCode >380 characters not print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787707/epson-escpos-qrcode-380-characters-not-print)

In my program I worked with the java.io.PrintWriter. This apparently only supports the ASCII character set up to Dec(127) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

If the QR is longer than 128 characters, an incorrect value is sent in the store_pL byte and the printer does not know the length of the transmitted data.

I solved the problem by not using the java.io.PrintWriter but the java.io.DataOutputStream.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
public class EscPos {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.10.45", 9100);
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

    String qrCode   = "123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 XX";

    int store_len = qrCode.length() + 3;
    byte store_pL = (byte) (store_len % 256);
    byte store_pH = (byte) (store_len / 256);
    
    outputStream.flush();
    // https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=140 (165)
        byte [] bSendFunktion165 = {(byte)0x1D, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x32, (byte)0x00};
        outputStream.write(bSendFunktion165);
    
    //https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=141 (167)
        byte [] bSendFunktion167 = {(byte)0x1D, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x43, (byte)0x9};
        outputStream.write(bSendFunktion167);
        
    //https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=142 (169)
        byte [] bSendFunktion169 = {(byte)0x1D, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x30};
        outputStream.write(bSendFunktion169);
        
    //https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=143 (180)
        byte [] bSendFunktion180 = {(byte)0x1D, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x6B, store_pL, store_pH, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x30};
        outputStream.write(bSendFunktion180);
        
        byte [] bSendQRCode = qrCode.getBytes();
        outputStream.write(bSendQRCode);
        
    //https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=143 (181)
        byte [] bSendFunktion181 = {(byte)0x1D, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x51, (byte)0x30};
        outputStream.write(bSendFunktion181);
    
        outputStream.flush();
        
        outputStream.write((byte)0x0A);
        outputStream.write((byte)0x0A);
        outputStream.write((byte)0x0A);
        outputStream.write((byte)0x0A);
        
        
        byte [] bCut = {(byte)0x1D, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x30};
        outputStream.write(bCut);        
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    outputStream.close();            
    sock.close();
    
    }
}
```

[image]

I hope I could help you. Happy holidays

Steffi

Comment: Hi, i think the issue is that i am not sending the stream directly to the printer, but wrinting them in a file, so the printing service (raw BT) Will use it to print. After the holidays, i Will test some other aproches, including yours. Many thanks and have yourself a merry christmas and the best for you on 2023. Many thanks